# Compiler Thought I Was Declaring Function Which I'm Not

Tags: c++

As title. Example:

```
#include <queue>
#include <vector>

class Foo {
    int n;
};

class Greater {
    const Foo& foo;

public:
    explicit Greater(const Foo& _foo): foo(_foo) {}

    bool operator()(int a, int b) const {
        return a > b;
    }
};

int main(void) {
    Foo foo;
    std::priority_queue<int, std::vector<int>, Greater> my_queue(Greater(foo));
    my_queue.push(30);

    return 0;
}
```

And I got the following error:

```
file.cpp: In function 'int main()':
file.cpp:22:14: error: request for member 'push' in 'my_queue', which is of 
non-class type 'std::priority_queue<int, std::vector<int>, Greater>(Greater)'
    my_queue.push(30);
             ^
```

Looks like compiler thought I'm declaring a function named 'my_queue' that receives `Greater` and returns a `std::priority_queue`.

I know I can do:

```
Greater greater(foo);
std::priority_queue<int, std::vector<int>, Greater> my_queue(greater);
```

and that compiled fine.

My question is, is that a bug in compiler/parser? What's prevented it from recognizing I'm trying to call `Greater`'s constructor instead of declaring parameter `Greater`?

I'm using GCC version 4.9.3.

Thank you.

Comment: You actually are declaring a function. It's not a bug. Anything that can be determined to be a function declaration is.

Comment: @Barry Oh! Thank you!